# Escape <?xml version="1.0" ?> tag from HTML

Tags: xml, html, hidden

I am trying to embedded a XML inside a HTML page with hidden div and using it latter to populate UI fields.

The problem is, I can't parse it since   tag is missing.

How can I escape the entire   tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not add that tag and then parse it?

Answer (score 0):

I would be better to put the content inside a hidden textarea, to keep your HTML markup correct.

Either way, you should be able to escape it by changing `<` to `&lt;` and `>` to `&gt;`.

(This should be done to the all of the XML tags, not only the `<?xml ?>` tag.)